# use DateTime or String in .net Web Service method sigs

Tags: c#, web-services, datetime

- which datatype is best to use for passing dates around my organisation from .net web services?

I am inclined to expose the services using DateTime fields - this means any client code (java, C# etc) will build appropriate stubs and the developer can use a natural and clean style for filling date fields.

However - I am not crystal clear as to whether this suitable for passing dates from different time zones.

An alternative would be to pass a string with a defined format and mandate that it should always represent UTC. That would be more messy, but might cause less confusion across the team.

thanks-

Comment: What are the values meant to represent? Points in time? Points in time with UTC offsets? Dates? (You might want to consider `DateTimeOffset`.)

Comment: More about DateTimeOffset. See also: [`SoapDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soapdatetime.aspx) class.

Comment: Hello Jon (hi to a fellow Readinger - I'm central Reading myself), and VMAtm. Generally we're representing points in time - eg the point at which an Order was taken. We have various business objects that might have date related fields in - ideally these would use a consistent and appropriate/generally useful type - hence SoapDateTime seems a bit odd in that context. DateTimeOffset looks interesting though...will test to see what a java client makes of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use DateTime datatype but when calling or passing the parameter in this function convert to UTC datetime.

Like in C#

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local)

DateTime.UtcNow
```

All the languages have such functions.

NOTE: We are creating a datetype again in UTC then a long datatype.